# Create a custom array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

I've played around with a personal project regarding a website listing PC games by year of releasing etc. (the topic it is not so important i guess) using the following structure for the links:

```
http://localhost/
http://localhost/?g=15
http://localhost/?g=30
http://localhost/?g=45
```

Like it is seen, I've display 15 games per page. What am I working right now is displaying the above links using php in a specific manner for each page (thumbnails, links, etc.):

```
$arr = array("","?g=15","?g=30","?g=45","?g=60","?g=75","?g=90");
foreach ($arr as $page) {
    $link = 'http://localhost/' . (string)$page;
    // do stuff to each page link
}
```

I am very satisfied with how it goes so far but I am wondering if there is a way to create the array automatically not requiring me to manually write the string, just specify the last multiple of 15 for example. I searched the web but I haven't find something concludent or maybe I don't express myself clear enough that's why any help is more than welcomed.

Comment: If you want to figure out what game is in the URL, and the key is "g", you can use `$_GET['g']` to get the value...

Comment: how the numbers are generating?

Comment: @Jimbo I've basically echo as the result something similar for example: `echo "<img src='" . $imgSrc . "'><br/><a href='" . $link . "'>Q2 of 2012</a>" ;` doing specific thing to each page link (specific image, text etc.) but I want automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily generate your array:

```php
<?php

$arr = array('');
$max = 5;
for($i = 0; $i < $max; ++$i) {
    $arr[] = '?g='.($i*15);
}

?>
```

Comment: thank you, now I've got it but it was necessary just to remove the first for loop to work properly for me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'http://localhost';

for ($i = 15; $i < $max; $i += 15) {
    echo "http://localhost/?g=$i";
}
```

In practice `$max` is calculated by how many entries there are, which is something you usually figure out from querying a database. Hope this points you in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

Thry this and tell me if it helps

```
$links = array();
$links[] = 'http://localhost/';
$multiplier = 5; //the mutiplier, number of links to provide
for ($i = 1; $i < $multiplier; $i++)
{
    $links[$i] = 'http://localhost/?g='.(15*$i);
    // do here what you want with $links[$i]              
}
print_r($links);
```